# How to organize site's public part with Angular 4 (or another fm)?

Tags: angular, reactjs, architecture, frameworks, frontend

I have next situation. Site divided into admin and front-end.

Admin developed completely with Angular 4 and I'm very pleased with it. Angular-cli etc. Very good stuff for SPA with one entry point.

But confused with front-end. It written with Laravel and will be rendered via it. Can't get how to use Angular 4 there, how to set workflow also.

Issues I should resolve on front - small, separate, but dynamic blocks, like currencies list or suggestion form.

Need some simple render framework/library without much dependencies and simple workflow.

Checked React - but it seems too complex for me.

**UPD:** For now thinking about Vue.js. It doesn't requires precompilation, can be applied at DOM element and it's components movable within system.

Answer (score 0):

Public part could b done with React or Vue - till both of them are modular and have not much boilerplate. I've chosen React.

My system config includes React and Webpack with Typescript

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        map: "./src/components/map/app.tsx",
        common: "./src/common.apps.tsx",
        share: "./src/components/objectshare.tsx",
        object: "./src/components/object/index.tsx",
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'socket.io-client', 'whatwg-fetch', 'mobx']
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "./../../html/js/public"
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
             { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
             { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
};
```

All magic is done with `entry` Webpack option. Each entry in `entry` creates proper file in public js location. Libraries is bundled to vendor and inserted in every page.

`Src` folder contains different folders for concrete pages (map, object etc.) and `common` folder for modules like utils, for example.

In backend I'm inserting needed scripts just basicly with `script` tag in page template.

Publishing compiled files directly to production folder called `html`.